# How can I look up other player's ranks while playing or drafting for hero league?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

When I play hero league I'd like to know the ranks of the other players. Is there some command I can type in the chatline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that when initiating in the "Allied team chat" you can right click on the other players' name in the chat and open their profile. A written message is needed to do this.

This enables you to look at the profiles of chatty teammates.